# Network service crashed - after command > npx cypress open

Tags: networking, runtime-error, cypress

How to fix error
[20164:0814/185206.944:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(470)] Network service crashed, restarting service.

after command > npx cypress open

Answer (score 1):

Founded issue:
The error was on version `^10.5.0`

If installing with this version in package.json file it is ok:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^9.7.0"
  }
}
```